# Replace a value in the Path variable

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, environment-variables

I'm trying to modify programatically the environment variables in windows, using cygwin `(version 4.4.12)`. I need to replace the existing PATH to a modified but on SETX instruction shows "the data that is saved is truncated to 1024 characters."

The original PATH:

> (...) c/Program Files
>   (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe:/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/d/Mis_documentos/Ahorititica/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin:/d/Program
>   Files/nodejs:/c/Users/fnoguera/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Sencha/Cmd/**6.5.3.6**:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

I just need to change a version number and set the same PATH:

> (...) c/Program Files
>   (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe:/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/d/Mis_documentos/Ahorititica/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin:/d/Program
>   Files/nodejs:/c/Users/fnoguera/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/Sencha/Cmd/**6.0.2.14**:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: Would you like to modify the path version for both Windows and Cygwin, or just for Cygwin ?

Comment: Just for Windows

Comment: Then edit the values of your environment variables ? [cross site duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: I'm doing a bash file to modify programatically a piece of the environment variables

Comment: Using `bash` to modify you windows host system environment variables is a very bad idea imo, especially in your case as you end up using Windows programs (`SETX` isn't part of `bash`, it's a windows program). Use the native tools Windows provides to do Windows-related tasks (i.e CMD or PowerShell).